# F# profiling and JIT_ChkCastAny

Tags: .net, f#

I'm profiling a bit of F# code with VS2010, and the profiler shows that about 20% of the time is spent in 'JIT_ChkCastAny', but doesn't go so far as to point to the offending bit of code.

Does anyone know what kinds of things in F# compile into something that invokes this method?

Update: By commenting out chunks of code, I've narrowed it down to the following methods:
Array.sumBy, Array.averageBy, Array.minBy, and Array.maxBy.  In each case, the numerical type parameter is double, so why is the compiled code so slow?

Comment: It's too difficult to say anything without a code fragment or a screenshot of what you have profiled?

Comment: If you want some help on improving performance of your code, please post a code fragment demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the implementation of `Array.sum` in [array.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs) (similar for `Array.sumBy`):

```
let inline sum (array: (^T)[] ) : ^T = 
    checkNonNull "array" array
    let mutable acc = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero< (^T) >
    for i = 0 to array.Length - 1 do
       acc <- Checked.(+) acc array.[i]
    acc
```

It does use `Checked.(+)` operator which has a lot of overheads. In case you wonder, the implementation of `Checked.(+)` in [prim-types.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs) <strike>uses Reflection</strike>. And the `JIT_ChkCastAny` term could result from using this `Checked` module.

I did the following measurement to compare between `Array.sum` and an implementation of sum using `Array.fold`:

```
#time "on";;
let arr = [|for i in 1..10000000 -> float i|];;
arr |> Array.sum;;
arr |> Array.fold (+) 0.;;
```

The second version is indeed a magnitude faster than the first one. Therefore, if `Array.sum` doesn't satisfy your requirement, you could use your own implementation of `sum`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `GenericZero` has no overhead at all. Interesting that the built-in accumulation functions are all checked; I would have expected them to be unchecked and possibly have alternative checked implementations. :-[

Comment: It would be great to provide unchecked versions too and let users decide.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I knew about the generic zero, but didn't realize that the checked operators were that much slower.

Comment: What makes you say that `Checked.(+)` uses reflection?  As far as I can see it only falls back on reflection if called dynamically.